# Redefining List of Theorems from thmtools to get Envname Number instead of Number

Tags: loops, thmtools

I'm trying to redefine the List of Theorems environment from [`thmtools`](https://ctan.org/pkg/thmtools) to typeset a List of Theorems that looks like

> Definition 1  Foo ......1
>
> Theorem 2 ..............2

rather than the usual

> 1  Definition (Foo) ....1
>
> 2 Theorem ..............2

My current attempt is this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheorem{theorem}
\declaretheorem[sibling=theorem]{definition}

\let\oldnumberline\numberline%
\renewcommand{\numberline}[1][\negmedspace]{#1 \oldnumberline}
\makeatletter
\@for\thmt@envname:=\thmt@allenvs\do{ 
    \def\ll@envname{%
            \protect\numberline[\thmt@thmname]{\csname the\thmt@envname\endcsname}%
            \ifx\@empty\thmt@shortoptarg%
            \else
                \thmt@shortoptarg%
            \fi
        }
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\begin{theorem}[Named Theorem]
\end{theorem}

\begin{definition}[Named Definition]
\end{definition}

\begin{definition}
\end{definition}

\listoftheorems
\end{document}
```

It seems to change nothing when compared with the usual construction. I believe the problem is the the `\@for` loop. I guess I might be running it wrongly, or using the wrong list of environments. I tried to construct it by looking at the `thmtools` [documentation](http://linorg.usp.br/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/thmtools/doc/thmtools-manual.pdf), as I couldn't really find the `\ll@envname` definition on the package's code. This belief is due to the fact that the following code does precisely what I have in mind, but works only for the `definition` environment (and I'd like to have something that works for all, without need to copy and paste the code every time I declare a new theorem):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheorem{theorem}
\declaretheorem[sibling=theorem]{definition}

\let\oldnumberline\numberline%
\renewcommand{\numberline}[1][\negmedspace]{#1 \oldnumberline}
\makeatletter
\def\ll@definition{%
        \protect\numberline[\thmt@thmname]{\csname the\thmt@envname\endcsname}%
        \ifx\@empty\thmt@shortoptarg%
        \else
            \thmt@shortoptarg%
        \fi
    }
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\begin{theorem}[Named Theorem]
\end{theorem}

\begin{definition}[Named Definition]
\end{definition}

\begin{definition}
\end{definition}

\listoftheorems
\end{document}
```

How can I correctly state the `\@for` loop so that the code generalizes to all declared theorem-like environments? Alternatively, is there another way of obtaining the result I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach, by providing a new `\listoftheorems` option `swapnumber`.

- *Update 1*: Make boolean option `swapnumber` more robust.
- *Update 2*: Make `swapnumber` compatible with unnumbered theorem.
- *Update 3*: Remove parentheses around the theorem names shown in `\listoftheorems`, by redefining `\thmtformatoptarg`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{xpatch}

% define new \listoftheorems option "swapnumber"
\makeatletter
\newif\ifthmt@listswap
\def\thmt@TRUE{true}
\def\thmt@FALSE{false}
\define@key{thmt-listof}{swapnumber}[true]{%
  \def\thmt@tmp{#1}%
  \ifx\thmt@tmp\thmt@TRUE
    \thmt@listswaptrue
  \else\ifx\thmt@tmp\thmt@FALSE
    \thmt@listswapfalse
  \else
    \PackageError{thmtools}{Unknown value `#1' to key swapnumber}{}%
  \fi\fi
}

% patch for unnumbered theorem
\xpatchcmd\thmt@mklistcmd
  {\protect\numberline{\protect\let\protect\autodot\protect\@empty}}
  {%
    \protect\ifthmt@listswap
    \protect\else
      \protect\numberline{\protect\let\protect\autodot\protect\@empty}%
    \protect\fi
  }
  {}{\fail}

% patch for numbered theorem
\xpatchcmd\thmt@mklistcmd
  {%
    \protect\numberline{\csname the\thmt@envname\endcsname}%
    \thmt@thmname
  }
  {%
    \protect\ifthmt@listswap
      \thmt@thmname~\csname the\thmt@envname\endcsname
    \protect\else
      \protect\numberline{\csname the\thmt@envname\endcsname}%
      \thmt@thmname
    \protect\fi
  }
  {}{\fail}
\makeatother

\declaretheorem{theorem}
\declaretheorem[sibling=theorem]{definition}
\declaretheorem[numbered=no]{axiom}

\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\begin{theorem}[Named Theorem]
\end{theorem}

\begin{definition}[Named Definition]
\end{definition}

\begin{definition}
\end{definition}

\begin{axiom}
\end{axiom}

\begin{axiom}[Named axiom]
\end{axiom}

\listoftheorems

\renewcommand\thmtformatoptarg[1]{ #1}
\listoftheorems[
  swapnumber, 
  title={List of Theorems (option \texttt{swapnumber} applied and parentheses removed)}
]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I find this approach particularly interesting because it still allows the option `onlynamed` to work properly. Do you think it is possible to remove the parentheses from around the names?

Comment: @NíckolasAlves You want `Theorem 1 Named Theorem` instead of `Theorem 1 (Named Theorem)`?

Comment: Yes, that's what I have in mind

Comment: @NíckolasAlves Yes it's possible. See my updated answer.

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The issue was actually quite silly. I was trying to redefine `\ll@envname`, which is not the command I wanted to redefine. Actually, I wanted to redefine `\csname ll@\thmt@envname \endcsname` (which I realized when reading line 800 of `thmtools`' code available in the documentation). The solution is then quite simple: just correct the name of the command I'm redefining, with the proper modifications with `\expandafter` (which is shortened to `\@xa` by `thmtools`) and so on.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheorem{theorem}
\declaretheorem[sibling=theorem]{definition}

\let\oldnumberline\numberline%
\renewcommand{\numberline}[1][\negmedspace]{#1 \oldnumberline}
\makeatletter
\@for\thmt@envname:=\thmt@allenvs\do{ 
    \@xa\def\csname ll@\thmt@envname\endcsname{%
            \protect\numberline[\thmt@thmname]{\csname the\thmt@envname\endcsname}%
            \ifx\@empty\thmt@shortoptarg%
            \else
                \thmt@shortoptarg%
            \fi
        }
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\begin{theorem}[Named Theorem]
\end{theorem}

\begin{definition}[Named Definition]
\end{definition}

\begin{definition}
\end{definition}

\listoftheorems
\end{document}
```